# define_method: How to dynamically create methods with arguments

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I want to create a bunch of methods for a find_by feature. I don't want to write the same thing over and over again so I want to use metaprogramming.

Say I want to create a method for finding by name, accepting the name as an argument. How would I do it? I've used define_method in the past but I didn't have any arguments for the method to take. 
Here's my (bad) approach

```
["name", "brand"].each do |attribute|
    define_method("self.find_by_#{attribute}") do |attr_|
      all.each do |prod|
        return prod if prod.attr_ == attr_
      end
    end
  end
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be aware if all is a large data set this could cause performance issues. Also I sincerely hope this is outside of the rails context as rails already implements `find_by_XXX` for every attribute.

Comment: Note: this will define two methods named `self.find_by_name` and `self.find_by_brand`. While it is possible to create such methods, it is impossible to call them using normal method calling syntax, because `.` is not a legal character in an identifier. Is there any particular reason why you want to define a method with an illegal name?

Comment: @engineersmnky
It's not rails! all just returns an array of `Products` for the inventory system of a Toy store. It's for the final project for the Ruby Nanodegree at Udacity.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I had no idea about that, and I was wondering why the NoMethodError, since I had a self.something method.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want something like this:

```
class Product
  class << self
    [:name, :brand].each do |attribute|
      define_method :"find_by_#{attribute}" do |value|
        all.find {|prod| prod.public_send(attribute) == value }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

(I'm assuming that the `all` method returns an Enumerable.)

The above is more-or-less equivalent to defining two class methods like this:

```
class Product
  def self.find_by_name(value)
    all.find {|prod| prod.name == value }
  end

  def self.find_by_brand(value)
    all.find {|prod| prod.brand == value }
  end
end
```

Comment: This works for me but... Can you explain how you got here? I searched for `class << self` and saw that it opens up a class and changes it's behavior but, why would I need to do that inside the class itself?

Comment: You need to do that because you want to define a class method. Without that, `define_method` will define an instance method, and `define_method("self.foo")` as in your example doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll look into it more to be more comfortable with Metaprogramming but for now, you helped me a lot! :)

Comment: The more idiomatic way would be to use `define_singleton_method`.

Comment: The distinction of defining a class method vs an instance method is extremely important for the sake of performance.  Thanks for mentioning that @Jordan

Answer (score 12):

It if you read the examples here http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/define_method you will find this one:

```
define_method(:my_method) do |foo, bar| # or even |*args|
  # do something
end
```

is the same as

```
def my_method(foo, bar)
   # do something
end
```

Comment: This keeps giving me a NoMethodError :/

Answer (score 2):

When you do this: `define_method("self.find_by_#{attribute}")`

that is incorrect. The argument to define_method is a symbol with a single word.

Let me show you some correct code, hopefully this will be clear:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  ["name", "brand"].each do |attribute|
    define_method(:"find_by_#{attribute}") do |attr_|
      first(attribute.to_sym => attr_)
    end
  end
end
```

This will produce class methods for `find_by_brand` and `find_by_name`.

Note that if you're looking into metaprogramming, this is a good use-case for method_missing. [here's a tutorial](https://technicalpickles.com/posts/using-method_missing-and-respond_to-to-create-dynamic-methods) to use method_missing to implement the same functionality you're going for (`find_by_<x>`)

Comment: If this is rails than this is a useless exercise since `find_by_XXX` is already defined. Also `define_method` can accept a String without issue.

Comment: `method_missing` is something I hate. There is no easy way to find methods defined in this way. Avoid if possible.

Comment: @akostadinov agreed