# How does ruby on rails dynamically define `find_by_id`, `find_by_name` methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am interested in understanding how `find_by_(column_name)` works.
How does Ruby on Rails dynamically define the method on calling `find_by_id`, `find_by_name`, etc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [define\_method: How to dynamically create methods with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233060/define-method-how-to-dynamically-create-methods-with-arguments)

Answer (score 2):

This is the power of meta programmation in Ruby, and more specifically the `method_missing` method: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing

When you call a method on an instance of a Class that is not defined in that class, the `method_missing` catches it and you can handle it there.